# handle service shutdown in WCF duplex session hosted in windows service

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, wcf

I have a Windows service hosting a WCF service that broadcasts information to several clients. I would like to gracefully handle a service shutdown from the client, i.e. detect that the service has dissapeared or wants to close, pop up a message and close the app. Currently if I shut down the service at the close line I get the following.

"The ServiceHost close operation timed out after 00:00:09.9910000.  This could be because a client failed to close a sessionful channel within the required time.  "

QUESTION: How do I detect the close request and shut the client down?

After the service closes on the client I get "Socket Exception ocurred An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

here is the close code.

```
If Not (_LivePricingHost Is Nothing) Then
    _LivePricingHost.Close()
    _LivePricingHost = Nothing
End If
```

Here is the class I use to set up the duplex sessions, I have removed the boilerplate dispose code and the events I am raising up to the client.

```
Imports System.ServiceModel

Public Class NotificationCallback
    ' Implements LivePricingService.IMessageCallback
    Implements IDisposable

    Private _ns As LivePricingService.MessageClient

    Public Sub New()
        Dim context = New InstanceContext(Me)

        _ns = New LivePricingService.MessageClient(context)
        _ns.SubscribeForBroadcast()
        '    _ns.AddMessage("PING")
    End Sub

 #End Region
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add an "Unsubscribe" method to the callback interface. Then the client can unsubscribe.
So when the service is stopping it asks the clients to disconnect.

```
   Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        pollTimer.Stop()
        _LivePricingWCFService.UnsubscribeAll()
        If Not (_LivePricingHost Is Nothing) Then
            _LivePricingHost.Close()
            _LivePricingHost = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
```

On the WCF service

```
   Public Sub UnsubscribeAll()
        Try
            RemoveClosedSubscribers()

            For Each callback As IMessageCallback In _subscribers
                If DirectCast(callback, ICommunicationObject).State = CommunicationState.Opened Then
                    callback.ShutDown() 'request that the client disconnect
                    _subscribers.Remove(callback)
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Logging.Logger.LogMessage(ex:=)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

and on the client

```
Public Sub ShutDown() Implements LivePricingService.IMessageCallback.ShutDown
    _ns.Close()
    Globals.LastException = New Exception("The Live Pricing Serice has shut down.")

End Sub
```